# Jmeter: Capture JDBC value in global variable

Tags: jdbc, properties, global-variables, jmeter

I'm very new to Jmeter and I'd like to know if there is some way to store the result of a query in a global variable to use in a different thread.

In other words, I need a set-up thread that sets a start-date and end-date (2 values) from the DB.
Then, in a second thread (the main thread), I have to use the start-date and end-date as parameters for the tests.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!,
Nahuel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following elements:

- [JDBC_Connection_Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration)
- [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request)
- [BeanShell Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler)
- [setUp Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#setUp_Thread_Group)

Organize them as following:
[image]

It will work as following:

1. JDBC Connection Configuration will setup the connection to DB, name Variable name so that it matches Variable name of JDBC Request, in my case I name it **conn**
2. Setup Thread Group will run query through JDBC Request and store result in variables
3. Beanshell sampler with use the value and store it as a property so it can be shared by all threads.

Note the following:

- The variable names of JDBC Request must match the number of columns returned by your SQL Query, note in example I have 3 columns, I put 3 variables, and will use clt_nom_1 name as I ensure there is only row returned by query

  - In Bean Shell sampler I put the following code:

    ```
    props.put("toto",vars.get("clt_nom_1"));
    ```
  - clt_nom_1 is named like this because it's the first row value
  - Finally in Thread Group I can use property toto through:

    ```
    ${__P(toto)}
    ```

[image: JDBC Request Example]

You could also replace BeanShell sampler by a debug sampler named:

```
${__setProperty(toto,${clt_nom_1})};
```

which would store variable in property

Comment: Setting the property using the debug sampler name was real neat. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it differently:
I created a BSF PostProcesser use 'Javascript' as the language:

```
var strData = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); //This is a string delimited with character return
var listData = strData.split('\n');
```

Then you can do all sort of things like from your list data, such as `vars.putObject`.

NOTE:It works with SELECT query on JDBC request.