# How to mapping query result into variables with jmeter

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, jdbc, jmeter

I must save the result of a JDBC Request into global variable so then use these to another query or sample.
I followed [this sample](http://90kts.com/2010/01/05/dynamic-data-from-jmeter-jdbc-requests/) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13522922/jmeter-capture-jdbc-value-in-global-variable) to save the result of query into totalNumber variable, but when I use this value to set the forEnd variable with this code in User Defined Variables

```
${__javaScript(${totalNumber} / ${sample})}
```

the forEnd is void because it can not retrieve the value of total Number.
Does someone has an idea?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved with BeanShell

```
${__BeanShell(${totalNumber}/${sample})}
```